# How to forgo promises when using async in a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

The following code makes use of a simple promise and works perfectly.

```
ipToDomain = (ip) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {  
    dns.reverse(ip, (err, domain) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(`ERROR: ${err.message}`)
      } else {
        resolve(domain);
      }
    });
  })
}
```

I'd like to convert this into the same function using async and removing the promise. It's my understanding that using async will wrap my function in a promise. This is just an academic exercise to fully understand how async works.

See here, which is from URL https://javascript.info/async-await:

> **Async functions**
>
> Let’s start with the async keyword. It can be placed before a
> function, like this:
>
> ```
> async function f() {
>   return 1;
> }
> ```
>
> The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function
> always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved
> promise automatically.
>
> For instance, this function returns a resolved promise with the result
> of 1; let’s test it:
>
> ```
> async function f() {
>   return 1;
> }
>
> f().then(alert); // 1
> ```
>
> …We could explicitly return a promise, which would be the same:
>
> ```
> async function f() {
>   return Promise.resolve(1);
> }
>
> f().then(alert); // 1
> ```

Unfortunately I can't get this function to work when I use async and forgo promises.

This doesn't work, but it outlines what I'm trying to do:

```
ipToDomain = async (ip) => {
    return dns.reverse(ip, (err, domain) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(`ERROR: ${err.message}`)
      } else {
        resolve(domain);
      }
    });
  })
}

(async () => {
  const result = await ipToDomain('1.2.3.4');
  console.log(result)
})();
```

Comment: You can't just use `await` because `dns.reverse` doesn't return a promise - you need `new Promise` so you get `resolve` and `reject`.

Comment: Since you're asking about node.js, the proper approach is to use `util.promisify` here. But that just hides the `new Promise`, it doesn't remove it. The solution to your academic exercise is: `async`/`await` does not work without promises. It is built on promises, and it provides no syntactic sugar for promisification.

Comment: I understand and thank you; I'd add though that this implementation does appear to add some syntactic sugar:

async function f() {
  return 1;
}

f().then(alert); // 1